# Prime number or not c++ cpp

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Q2. Nature numbers and their sum.

Write a program that:

- Asks the user to input an integer *n*;
- Prints all the natural numbers that are less than the *n* on the screen;
- Calculates the sum of all these nature numbers.

I've done most of it but don't know how I get the program to start the loop again after the wrong number is placed it automatically ends.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    //Ask the user to input an integer
    cout << "Input an integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    if ( n > 0){
        for (i = 1 ; n > i ; i++ )
        {
        //Calculate sum of differences
            sum += i;
        //Prints all the natural numbers that are less than the *n* on the screen;
            cout << i << ", ";
        }
    }
        else
    {
        cout << "Place a positive integer" <<endl;
    }
    //printed sum
    
    cout << "\nthe sum of these numbers is: " << sum << endl;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
while(cin >> n) {
  if ( n > 0){
    for (i = 1 ; n > i ; i++ )
    {
    //Calculate sum of differences
        sum += i;
    //Prints all the natural numbers that are less than the *n* on the screen;
        cout << i << ", ";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Place a positive integer" <<endl;
  }
}
```